# %s without accompanying variable - how does this work?

Tags: python

I've been looking over some github repos of python scrapy spiders. In this [repo](https://github.com/ambidere/seidownpy/blob/master/seidownpy/spiders/TumblrSpider.py) I found the following lines of code:

```
FIRSTPAGE_URL_SYNTAX = 'http://%s.tumblr.com'
OTHERPAGE_URL_SYNTAX = 'http://%s.tumblr.com/page/%s'
name = "tumblr"
```

According to the documentation and SO thread that I've found, `%s` requires an in-line reference to a variable. As you can see the code above contains no such reference. Is this working code? Why?

Comment: If you explicitly quote & provide links for "the documentation ... I've found", we can help you find your misunderstanding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those variables serve as a template.  Later in the code, you'll see something like

```
FIRSTPAGE_URL_SYNTAX % user
```

or

```
OTHERPAGE_URL_SYNTAX % (user, page)
```

You can do the same thing with `{}` in strings:

```
template = "{} blah blah {}"

print(template.format(s1, s2))
```

This allows for a user to easily repeatedly use this one variable, if they need to reference multiple URLs with similar bodies, as opposed to having to retype the entire URL every time.

Comment: If you are able to replace certain characters of a string with things such as `%` or `{}` in other languages it is general. A `template` is not the actual python name, but rather a description, similar to a `class`, where it is the abstract broader definition, where when actually implementing it you will make it more specific

Answer (score 2):

Those are just strings. All characters, including `%s`, are valid in strings. The requirement for a substitution value comes when you use the `%` operator, which they're not doing here. They're declaring those strings as templates, and will substitute values into them later.

By declaring them all in one place like that, it makes it easier to find them and change them. It's good coding practice.